# Xamarin Forms Maps Custom Pin looking like own position

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application with a `Xamarin.Forms.Map` map displaying movable objects. I would like to add my own `CustomPin` that looks exactly like the Pin showing the own location, without a needle, but maybe with a different color. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

[image]

I already found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin) tutorial on the MS website, which is pretty detailed. But I was hoping there was a way to simply overwrite the default pin (annotation view on iOS) with the view of the user's current position.

Comment: Have you tried using an image?

Comment: You can override the `CreateMarker(Pin pin)` method and use `SetIcon` for a custom map pin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin#customizing-the-marker

Comment: @ChristopherStephan thanks. I knew that. The thing is, I don't want _custom_ I want the _own location_ pin.